# Complicated VLOOKUP on Excel

Tags: excel, search, vlookup, spreadsheet, synonym

I am trying to analyze the efficiency of synonyms I have saved on our webshop. I have a list of about 5000 synonyms and want to vlookup them on a list of 1.000.000 queries with the help of Excel. The problem is, that on each "synonym cell" I might have multiple synonyms separated by a blank space. These synonyms I want to find in a list of query strings. Eventually whenever there is a match, I wish to find the product attached to that synonym in the referring cell "VLOOKUP" and count them all together to see how many sales I have gotten with the help of synonyms.

Hopefully this explanation is not too complicated and you can help me out finding each synonym in the search queries. If you have a better idea on how to do this procedure more efficiently, that would be even better. :-)

Here is some sample data that explains well, what I am going for:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UASfryBJ6pQiAqVy8Z6dJ1klJkUzCu4UZZCunjAIDFg/edit?usp=sharing

Feel free to edit it and thanks a lot!
Nes

Answer (score 0):

In order to vlookup a synonum (found in column B of worksheet "synonyms", maybye you have to restruct worksheet "synonyms" like this :

```
| synonym | product |

| -------- | -------|

| icecream | cake1  |

| sweets   | cake1  |
```

After that you need to split query column in sevral columns (one word per column) and vlookup each of this words in the restructered synonyms worksheet

Answer (score 0):

With that much data, and using Excel, I'd suggest using Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and O365).

- Read in the queries table

  - split the query into separate columns by the space delimiter
  - unpivot to create a single column of the query words
- Read in the synonyms table
- split the synonyms into separate columns by the space delimiter
- unpivot to create a single column of the synonyms
- Do a nested fuzzy join of the two tables

  - fuzzy so you can do things like `IgnoreCase` and set an appropriate `Threshold` to allow for single vs plural words, and minor misspellings in the queries.
- Recombine the split column to create an output table

*you may need to tweak things like the column splitter and the threshold depending on your real data. Also I've only allowed for a single synonym and pdroduct. The column splitter can be rewritten to handle any number of columns, and I'll look at that if I have time later today*

*I tried to comment the M-code to explain things*

***Note the table names in lines 4 and 18 of the code. You may need to change these (or, if reading them from an external source, change that line entirely).***

**M Code**

*paste into Advanced Editor in PQ*

```
let

//Read in Query Table and convert to single column of words in query
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblQuery"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"query", type text}, {"bought", type text}}),

    //add an index column for eventual reconstruction
    #"Add Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type1","Index",0,1),
   
    //may need more splits depending on real data
    splitIt = Table.SplitColumn(#"Add Index", "query", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), 
        {"query.1", "query.2", "query.3"}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns1" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(splitIt, {"Index", "bought"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    queryTbl = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns1",{"Attribute"}),

    //Read in synonym table
    //unpivot to convert to two column table
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblSyno"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"product", type text}, {"query-synonym", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "query-synonym", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"query-synonym.1", "query-synonym.2", "query-synonym.3"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"query-synonym.1", type text}, {"query-synonym.2", type text}, {"query-synonym.3", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type2", {"product"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    synoTbl = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),

    //combine tables based on synonyms
    //combTbl = Table.NestedJoin(queryTbl,"Value",synoTbl,"Value","Joined",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    combTbl = Table.FuzzyNestedJoin(queryTbl,"Value",synoTbl,"Value","Joined",JoinKind.LeftOuter,
            [IgnoreCase=true, Threshold=0.9]),

    //extract the synonym
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(combTbl, "Synonym", each try Table.Column([Joined],"Value"){0} 
                            otherwise null),
    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Attached Product", each try Table.Column([Joined],"product"){0}
otherwise null),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom4",{"Joined"}),

    //Recombine by the Index column to recreate the query
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Index"}, {{"Group", each _, type table [bought=nullable text, Index=number, Value=text, Joined=table, Synonym=nullable text]}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Index"}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "query", each Table.Column([Group],"Value")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom1", 
        {"query", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), " "), type text}),
    
    //extract the "bought" column from the group table
    //if there might be more than one product in 
        //the "bought" column, need to change this
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Values", "bought", each 
        List.Distinct(Table.Column([Group],"bought")){0}),

    //extract the Matched Synonym column
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Matched Synonym", each List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column([Group],"Synonym")){0}),

    //extract the Attached Product column
    #"Added Custom5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom3", "Attached Product", each List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column([Group],"Attached Product")){0}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom5",{"Group"})
in
    #"Removed Columns2"
```

**Synonym Table**

[image]

**Results**

[image]